# not able to pass form data to php and save data in XML

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml

not able to pass form data to php
I am using AJAX in Jquery to pass form field variables to php and using php i want those data should get saved in a XML file in a AEM bin or clientlib.

I am not able to pass those data to PHP using ajax .this is what i am doing:

```
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var n1=$('#Name').val();
        var em1=$('#Email').val();
        var org1=$('#Org').val();
        var ph1=$('#phone').val();
        var c1=$('#Country').val();
        var ic1=$('#Inquiry_Contact').val();  
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/etc/designs/team-a/clientlibs/scripts/dummy.php",
           dataType: "xml",
            contentType: "application/xml",
          data:"{'Name':'" + n1 + "','email':'" + em1 + "','organisation':'"                 + org1 + ",'phone':"+ph1+",'country':"+c1+",'inquiry-contact':"+ic1+"}", 
        success: function (res) {
       alert("thank you"+n1+" we will contact you soon");
          },
         error: function (res) {
     alert("XML: not working! " + res.statusText);
        }
      });
       }
```

And this is my php file:

```
    <?php
      $data=$_REQUEST['data']
      $n1 = $_POST['n1'];
      $em1 = $_POST['em1'];
      $org1 = $_POST['org1'];
      $ph1 = $_POST['ph1'];
      $c1 = $_POST['c1'];
      $ic1 = $_POST['ic1'];

     $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
     $xml->formatOutput = true;
     $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
     $xml->load('data.xml');

      $element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('reports')->item(0);

     $ic1 = $element->getElementsByTagName('ic1')->item(0);
     $n1 = $element->getElementsByTagName('n1')->item(0);
     $em1 = $element->getElementsByTagName('em1')->item(0);
     $org1 = $element->getElementsByTagName('org1')->item(0);
     $ph1 = $element->getElementsByTagName('ph1')->item(0);
     $c1 = $element->getElementsByTagName('c1')->item(0);

     $newItem = $xml->createElement('reports');
     $newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('ic1', $_POST['ic1']));
     $newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('n1', $_POST['n1']));
     $newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('em1', $_POST['em1']));
     $newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('org1', $_POST['org1']));
     $newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('ph1', $_POST['ph1']));
     $newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('c1', $_POST['c1']));
     $xml->getElementsByTagName('reports')->item(0)->appendChild($newItem);
     $xml->save('data.xml');
      echo "Data has been written.";
    ?>
```

BUT its not working....i thing this php is not called ...their is some issue in ajax only.
Looking forward for a help
thanks in advance:

Answer (score 0):

Changed data in ajax and shown below

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/etc/designs/team-a/clientlibs/scripts/dummy.php",
            dataType: "xml",
            contentType: "application/xml",
            data:{   //changed data like this
                  Name:n1 , 
                  email:em1,
                  organisation:org1,
                  phone:ph1,
                  country:c1,
                  inquirycontact:ic1  //changed from inquiry-contact to inquirycontact to avoid syntax errors 
             },
            success: function (res) {
                alert("thank you"+n1+" we will contact you soon");
            },
            error: function (res) {
                alert("XML: not working! " + res.statusText);
            }
        });
```

This will sent data as array of key-value pair, which your php script can access. 
Hope this solves ajax problem :)